# Random sampling and assigning values to each sample set in Tableau

Tags: sql, random, tableau-api, row-number

I have a tableau dashboard that provides tasks for auditing based on the date filter we choose. The total number of tasks that we may get for a given date would be around 700. We have 5 team members to do a total of 120 tasks per day (5*25 tasks).

I am trying to assign tasks to the 5 members by doing a random sample of the tasks and then assign 25 tasks each to 5 members.

Trying to implement something similar to 
rownumber(over() order by random) as proxy 
select 
case 
when proxy >=25 then 'set 1'
when proxy >=50 then 'set 2' and so on.

Is that possible in Tableau

Comment: What happens to the other 580 tasks?  Something seems off balance.  Also tag with the underlying database that you are using.

Comment: I am trying to create a calculated field with header "Auditor" and it will have these values "Set 1", "set 2" -- "set 5" and "Not assigned" for the remaining 580 tasks .

Comment: Please give your feedback whether it worked the way you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I am also in auditing, so sampling is nearly everyday task for me.  In order to replicate you problem, I created a fake data in Excel having row_id as `ID` and 100 of these for each `Date`.

```
ID   | Date
1    | 01-01-2020
...
100  | 01-01-2020
101  | 02-01-2020
...
300  | 03-01-2020
```

After importing in Tableau (I'll show for 5 Audit sets of 5 IDs each day, you can replicate it for 25 or any other number)..

**Step-1** Create a calculated field `CF` as

```
Random()*1000
```

**Note** Random() is a working function in tableau despite not being listed.

**Step-2** Create another calculated field `CF2` as

```
RANK_UNIQUE(sum([CF]), 'desc')
```

**Step-3** change table calculation options as

[image]

**Step-4** Create desired calculated field `audit set` as

```
IF INT(([CF2]-1)/5) = 0 THEN 'Audit Set-1'
ELSEIF INT(([CF2]-1)/5) = 1 THEN 'Audit Set-2'
ELSEIF INT(([CF2]-1)/5) = 2 THEN 'Audit Set-3'
ELSEIF INT(([CF2]-1)/5) = 3 THEN 'Audit Set-4'
ELSEIF INT(([CF2]-1)/5) = 4 THEN 'Audit Set-5'
ELSE 'Not assigned'
END
```

You will get desired IDs/rows as the following view, which will serve your purpose

[image]

**Needless to say that you can select 25 per set by integer dividing the `CF2-1` by 25 instead of 5 as done in last calculated field.**

After a little tweak you can get a view like this

[image]